# Weird row-count return for PHP/MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've checked this in phpMyAdmin, and it returned 1 result:

```
    SELECT id, name
      FROM tbl_product_category
INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket
        ON id = basket.cat_id
     WHERE basket.product_id = 2
     LIMIT 0,1
```

I then checked this in phpMyAdmin, and it returned COUNT = 1:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM tbl_product_category
INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket
        ON id = basket.cat_id
     WHERE basket.product_id = 2
     LIMIT 0,1
```

Now I don't understand why this causes `$rows` to return empty string or null:

```
function getProductCategory($product_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category
        INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket
                ON id = basket.cat_id
             WHERE basket.product_id = ?
             LIMIT 0,1;";
    $data = array((int)$product_id);
    $rows = dbRowsCount($sql, $data);
logErrors("getProductCategory(".$product_id.") returned rows: ".$rows);
    if ($rows == 1) {
        dbQuery($sql, $data);
        return dbFetch();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `logErrors` method gives me this output:

> getProductCategory(1) returned rows:
>   getProductCategory(2) returned rows:
>   getProductCategory(3) returned rows:
>   getProductCategory(4) returned rows:
>   getProductCategory(5) returned rows:

and so I'm returning `null` from the method.

My `dbRowsCount(...)` method converts the SQL to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, then `dbQuery(...)` executes the real query. This is strange because the `dbRowsCount(...)` so far has always returned the correct rows for my other queries.

Here it is anyway:

```
function dbRowsCount($sql, $data) {
    global $db, $query;
    $regex = '/^SELECT\s+(?:ALL\s+|DISTINCT\s+)?(?:.*?)\s+FROM\s+(.*)$/i';
    if (preg_match($regex, $sql, $output) > 0) {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$output[1]}");
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if ($data != null)
            $query->execute($data);
        else
            $query->execute();
        if (!$query) {
            echo "Oops! There was an error: PDOStatement returned false.";
            exit;
        }
        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So what's gone wrong?

---

## Edit

Here is some output from my program:
[Original Query]
[Query after regex]

```
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(1) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(2) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(3) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(4) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(5) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(6) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(7) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(8) returned rows: 7
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_product_category INNER JOIN tbl_product_cat_basket AS basket ON id = basket.cat_id WHERE basket.product_id = ? LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category

getProductCategory(9) returned rows: 7
SELECT * FROM tbl_store_admin WHERE php_sesskey=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_store_admin WHERE php_sesskey=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;

SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY last_update ASC;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product ORDER BY last_update ASC;
```

Comment: What does `$output[1]` look like?

Comment: `var_dump("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$output[1]}");`

Comment: @jeroen @zerkms For some reason it started returning $rows = 7 now! and the output of the regex is this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category` which is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegeExp doesn't match, it's missing the dot-all flag (/is in total).

This causes `.` to also match newlines in your string.

Comment: I think you missed the `FROM` cause its on the same-line as `SELECT`, but yeah I have a `FROM` there.

Comment: Maybe because you're missing the multi-line flag in your regexp? Try /im instead of just /i

Comment: @ccKep: with `m` modifier `^` is treated as a line beginning, not a string beginning. `s` is what perhaps you wanted to say

Comment: In that case, let's take it the other way around: Did you test if your regexp even matches your $sql ? [link](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) Only works if I add the multi-line flag to your pattern.

Comment: @ccKep: just a side note, I'm not an OP

Comment: @cckep since I started printing the $output, the function started return 7 rows instead of an empty string, and it converts the sql to this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_product_category` which is wrong because it left out the WHERE clause

Comment: `$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$output[1]}");` define "wrong", you're not using any WHERE clauses there.

Comment: @ccKep It works for other queries `SELECT * FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;` converts to this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_menu_cat_basket WHERE menu_id=?;` through the same function

Comment: Try the dot-all flag on your regexp (/is in total) [as zerkms suggested already a few comments higher]

Comment: @ccKep wow that was it! Thanks guys!! (btw you should probably edit your answer to add that info)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your regex is not returning the correct result. As you are only looking for the first occurrence of `FROM` and return everything after that, why don't you just use [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)?

```
$output = stristr($sql, 'FROM');    // $output includes 'FROM'
if ($output !== false)
{
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) {$output}");
    // etc.
```